# PowerShell - Return value of AD User's First and Last name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to pull a users first and last name from AD using PowerShell.

The commands:

```
$GivenName = Get-ADUser -Identity $User | select GivenName
Write-Host $GivenName
```

returns a value of: `@{GivenName=Bruce}`
I then tried to reduce the string down to just the part i need with the following commands:

```
$First = $GivenName.Replace("@{GivenName=","")
$First = $First.Replace("}","")
```

This should strip away all except for the string 'Bruce'

Instead I get this following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser] does not contain a method named 'Replace'.
At C:\Users\john.ring\Documents\Scripts\UpdateADUsers.ps1:10 char:5
+     $First = $GivenName.Replace("@{GivenName=","")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Replace:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

My Google-fu has failed to find a solution.  Any suggestion on how to correct the error or a better way to pull the users first name would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Select -Expand GivenName`

Comment: Thanks Mathias!  That does exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pipe objects to `Select-Object [propertyname(s)]`, the `Select-Object` cmdlet creates a new object for you, with the properties from the input object that you specified. This object in turn ends up being rendered as `@{PropertyName1=PropertyValue1[;PropertyNameN=PropertyValue2]}` when converted to a string.

To grab the value of a single property, and nothing else, use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter:

```
$GivenName = Get-ADUser -Identity $user |Select-Object -ExpandProperty GivenName
```

Since you need multiple properties from the same user, better store the the user in a variable and use the `.` dereference operator to access the `GivenName` and `Surname` properties:

```
$UserObject = Get-ADUser -Identity $user 
$GivenName  = $UserObject.GivenName
$Surname    = $UserObject.Surname
```

Answer (score 0):

`GivenName` is a user object attribute in Active Directory. You're storing the results of your query in a PowerShell object called `$GivenName`, however the two are not the same. To reference the user's given name, you need to reference the GivenName property of the PowerShell object. `$GivenName.GivenName` is what you are looking for.

It might be less confusing if you store the results of your AD query in an object named `$User` instead, so `$User.GivenName` is how you would reference the given name property.